# Is it true that $ \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{f(t)}{g(t)} = 1? $

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\alpha, c, k, p \in \mathbb{R}^{>0}$. I assume that $t > \dfrac{p}{c\alpha}$.

Let $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ be a functions defined by

$$
f(t) := 4kp \ln\left(\dfrac{c \alpha t}{p} e \right), \qquad \qquad t \in (\dfrac{p}{c \alpha}, \infty)
$$

and
$$
g(t)  := \dfrac{kp}{n_0} + 4k e^{\frac{-\alpha t}{4n_0}}, \qquad \qquad t \in (\dfrac{p}{c \alpha}, \infty)
$$
where
$$
n_0 := \left\lceil\dfrac{\alpha t}{4 \ln\left(\dfrac{c \alpha t}{p}\right)} \right \rceil \in \mathbb{N}.
$$

Is it true that 
$$
\lim_{t \to \infty} \dfrac{f(t)}{g(t)} = 1?
$$

Comment: What is $\lim_{t \to +\infty} f(t)$? and $\lim_{t \to +\infty} g(t)$?

Answer (score 1):

We have 
$$
f(t)=4kp \ln(t) +O(1)
$$
and
$$
g(t)=O(1),
$$
since $e^{-a}\le 1$ for every $a>0$ and $n_0\rightarrow \infty$ as $t\rightarrow\infty$.
Consequently, 
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(t)}{g(t)}=\infty.
$$